# Transfer of valid Canadian visa to new passport

Tags: visas, canada, passport-renewals

I have renewed my passport and want to transfer my Canadian Visa to the  new passport. Can I do it? If yes, then what will be the  validity of the visa, same or it can be extended by the Canadian Consulate with its discretion upto the validity of the new Passport?

Comment: Do not, under any circumstances try to move the visa sticker from one passport to the other. The answer will be either (a) when you travel to Canada, take both passports with you or (b) you must get a new visa. I'm sure somebody who knows how Canadian visas work will answer your question.

Comment: Canada doesn't transfer visas.  You can apply for a new visa, but as noted in the answers to the linked duplicate question, it is not necessary to do so.